# Large configurable products are causing Internal Server Error on category page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

When I add product with large amount of configurations it causes category to return Internal Server Error Page:

Product 1 - 184 subproducts - works

Product 2 - 124 subproducts - works

Product 3 - 4518 subproducts - causes Internal Server Error

Any clues why this might happen? All the other subpages are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely occur because you have too much configuration and the page takes too much time to load. Check your server error log for more information.

If you cant find the logs, try to change your php setting max_execution_time and put a high number like 300 . If the page ends up loading it is because your configurable contains too much simple products. Even if it fix your issue, revert your change to the max_execution_time, having a page that takes more than 30 seconds to load is not a viable option.

If the problem is because the page takes too much time to load check if you didn't add some code that could slow down the process and fix it. Otherwise you should try to find a way to split this big configurable product into smaller configurable product if it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your insight! The page loads in less than a second on my local and the execution time is already set to something extreme.

Comment: Do you have more details about the error in your exception.log, php logs or server logs?